# Google Pixel not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Having trouble with Android Studio connecting to my Pixel phone. I'm sort of out of ideas and am looking for suggestions. I feel like I'm missing an obvious step.

Things I've done:

Made sure developer options is on with USB debugging on.

Have tried switching from MTP to PTP.

My computer recognizes the Pixel just fine under windows 8.

Made sure android studio is up to date including "Google USB Driver" installed under SDK tools.

My previous phone (Droid mini) connects just fine.

Tried different USB ports for the cable to my phone.

Comment: Does `adb devices` list your pixel?

Comment: Nope, not listed there.

Comment: But the ADB Device is visible in Device Manager?

Comment: Don't see it under device manager. To make sure I understand your question i can still see my other phone if connected.

Comment: Does the Phone show "USB-Debugging" in the status bar? My phone sometimes "forgets" to keep it enabled.

Comment: It will display it there, haven't seen it go away at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131099/discussion-between-jonas-koritz-and-zoltar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Studio / SDK Manager will provide the driver but Windows might not automatically install it for your device. Try checking the device manager, unplugging and reconnecting the device or let the device manager search for new hardware.

The driver (when installed via SDK Manager) will be found by windows when provided with the SDK root directory, usually `AppData/Local/Android/sdk`

Comment: If this process doesn't resolve for device `Pixel 2` look for an adjacent `ADB device` and try updating that driver.

Answer (score 40):

Encountered this problem today as I tested on other people's phones. I found 4 possibilities why a device may not be recognized:

- Case #1: The USB cable supports charging but not data transfer.
- Case #2: Developer options haven't been enabled on target phone (see: https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-215055/)
- Case#3: Developer options enabled, but USB debugging hasn't been enabled. Go to Settings > System > Developer Options > USB Debugging
- Case #4: Some (but not all) phones require MTP transfer mode to be enabled. It can be enabled by sliding a finger from the top of the screen and tapping "Android system - USB charging this device" > Tap for more options > Transfer files.

Hope this helps someone ^_^

---

**EDIT:**
It's come to my attention that there's another possibility. I don't know what causes this, but if you get really stuck, sometimes you need to go into Settings > Developer Options > Debugging > Revoke USB debugging authorisations. This will reset your device USB pairing fingerprint which will often bring the phone back as a device target in Android Studio.

Comment: It worked for me when I selected option 'Transfer Files'. Thanks

Comment: The "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" fixed it for me.  Thank you so much for that!!!

Comment: The "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" step was critical for me too.   Then a unplug / replug of the USB cable to the Pixel 3 phone brought up the authorization dialog.  This menu item is located in the "Developer options" menu.

Comment: Case #4 fixed it for me. I'm using a pixel 4a. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In Pixel devices USB debugging is enable when:

`Step 1.` **Enable Developer Options** to double tap on Build Number, you can get it by search with build in setting.

`Step 2.` **Enable USB debugging Option**, to enable this just to search usb debugging in settings.

`Step 3.` Pixel devices require **USB tethering  mode to be enabled**, It can be enabled by sliding a finger from the top of the screen and tapping "Android system - USB use for " > Tap on USB tethering.

After completion of all these steps you will be able to use you pixel device as enabled for debugging in SDK.

Comment: Step 3 is bollocks (not true).

Comment: My Pixel 4a stopped being detected by Android Studio and ADB. I did Step 3, enabling USB tethering mode, and this helped me with my Pixel 4a. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same trouble with my Google Pixel 2 (Android 9); I couldn't connect it to ADB in Android Studio 3.3. In my special case, AS runs on Kubuntu 18.04 in a VMware Workstation on a Windows host.
I have to do following steps every time I want to connect the phone (the phone is already in developer mode):

- Plug phone via USB into the computer (and connect it to the VMware guest, if you use it)
- Phone: Swipe down the notification bar, there should be a message 'Charging the device via UDB'
- Tab on it and change the 'Use USB for' from 'No data transfer' to 'File trasfer'

You can activate 'USB debugging' on your phone's developer screen before or after this procedure, both works for me.

Answer (score 3):

That happened to me with a generic Type C to USB Cable (White Cable in the Picture Attached). Then I bought another Cable (The Black one in the Picture Attached) and it worked perfectly. It was the Cable. Make sure to have one that says "Data & Power".

Hope it helps!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution to device not found when running adb devices from windows 7 standard terminal for my Pixel 4a 5g was to simply update my google USB drivers. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Answer (score 0):

If dev options aren't available, double click the build number until a notification appears stating dev options have been enabled.

Comment: Please add steps to enable dev options, it will help for readers.